# Stepper Inside Listview not showing incremented value correctly

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a XF UI where, I have a Listview inside which, I have a Stepper Control. I am binding the ListView Using ItemSource Property

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TicketList,Mode=TwoWay}" >
```

The Stepper Control within along with Entry Box to Show its Value has its binding as follows.

```
<Entry Text="{Binding SelectedQuantity,Mode=TwoWay}"></Entry>
<Stepper Increment="1" Maximum="{Binding AvailableTickets}" Minimum="0" 
                         Value="{Binding SelectedQuantity,Mode=TwoWay}"></Stepper>
```

The Controls loads in well, with the correct values. However, when i try to increment the Stepper, I can see the Stepper seems working (it reaches max/min and greys out), but I am not able to reflect the incremented value in the Entry Box.

Could someone help me understand how I can change the value in Entry Control reflecting the value in Stepper ?

I am using Prism and would ideally prefer bindings to writing C# code for manipulating ValueChange Evenet.

**Update**

Adding Model Code

```
    public class TicketModel
{

    public int SelectedQuantity { get; set; }

}
```

The Collection which is bound to ListView is defined as

```
        private ObservableCollection<TicketModel> _TicketList;
    public ObservableCollection<TicketModel> TicketList
    {
        get { return _TicketList; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _TicketList, value); }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: does your model implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Hi Jaison, infact I am using Prism and the properties are using SetProperty.

Comment: I would set a breakpoint in the SelectedQuantity property getter/setter and make sure the code is getting executed, also look for binding errors in your debugger output.

Comment: Hi Bill, Actually SelectedQuantity is not implemented as property. It is a sub property of Model from TicketList the ObservableCollection<Model> which binds to the Listview. Like i mentioned, the stepper is inside a listview

Comment: Can you add the code for Model (at least the part where SelectedQuantity is defined)?

Comment: Hi Bill, I have added the Model as well as the Collection to which the ListView is bound to.

Comment: You need to implement PropertyChanged on your SelectedQuanitity property. Just because it's an ObservableCollection doesn't mean it tracks individual properties in your objects in the list. So with Prism you could use SetProperty inside your SelectedQuantity property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to raise property changed on your SelectedQuantity property, an ObservableCollection only makes it so the ListView responds to items being added and removed from your collection automatically, it does nothing for the individual properties in the items in your collection. Also your TwoWay binding on ItemsSource won't have any effect and there is no reason to make that a TwoWay binding.

Here is my code that worked for me:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    int selectedQuantity;
    public int SelectedQuantity
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedQuantity;
        }
        set
        {
            if (selectedQuantity != value)
            {
                selectedQuantity = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedQuantity"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my XAML:

```
  <StackLayout>
    <Entry Text="{Binding SelectedQuantity,Mode=TwoWay}"></Entry>
    <Stepper Increment="1" Maximum="10" Minimum="0"
                             Value="{Binding SelectedQuantity,Mode=TwoWay}"></Stepper>    
  </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Bill, Actually SelectedQuantity is not implemented as property. It is a sub property of Model from TicketList the ObservableCollection<Model> which binds to the Listview. Like i mentioned, the stepper is inside a listview

Comment: Thank You Bill, That Worked.